# Count number of times, a number appears and update it to a different column

Tags: mysql

I am not sure how to do this in mysql, i have searched but I can't seem to find a solution.
, 
I have a table like so.

```
id pid occurrence  
1  23  blank
2  23  blank
3  44  blank
```

Basically, occurrence should have the value of 2, for id 1,2 and a value of 1 for id 3. 
Any help would be appreciated. I can easily call count and GROUP BY, and get the number of times each one occurance, but I would like to update column occurrence in the right place for each pid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the correct `occurrence` value you can do

```
select pid, count(*) as occurrence
from your_table
group by pid
```

To update the table do

```
update your_table t1
join 
(
    select pid, count(*) as occurrence
    from your_table
    group by pid
) t2 on t1.pid = t2.pid
set t1.occurrence = t2.occurrence
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value in the table, use `update` with a `join`:

```
update table t join
       (select pid, count(*) as cnt
        from table 
        group by pid
       ) tt
       on tt.pid = t.pid
    set t.occurrence = tt.cnt;
```